# Warning message: "The Snagit capture hotkey is in use by another program"

Tags: snagit

I've created a new Snagit capture profile and want to assign the <kbd>Print screen</kbd> hotkey to it.

For that, I open the *Change Capture Hotkey* dialog of my profile and try to change *None* to *Print screen*.

[image: Change capture hotkey]

When I try that, I get the following warning message:

> The Snagit capture hotkey is in use by another program. Select a
>   different keyboard combination for the hotkey.

[image: Snagit warning]

How do I need to proceed to be able to assign the *Print screen* hotkey to my profile?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I need to proceed to be able to assign the *Print screen*
>   hotkey to my profile?

The general solution is to find the other program that is currently using the *Print screen* hotkey and remove it there so it can be used from within Snagit.

In this particular case, it's Snagit itself that is already using this hotkey. Unfortunately, the hotkey is not visible in the "Manage Profiles" window.

1. You have to open Snagit from the Windows notification area.
2. Then select *Menu: Preferences* → *Tab: Hotkeys*.
3. Under *Global capture* change *Print screen* to *None*.
   [image: Global capture]
4. Now you can go back to your own profile and assign *Print screen* as the hotkey without getting the warning message.